# Setting cell row value in DataGrid from object's property but using that property to fetch some other value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I need to fetch institution name for a given `Classroom` and place that name in `DataGrid`. Here is what I have so far.

This is some globally available static hash map, which will store `Institution` objects, key is `Id` of that `Institution`.

```
 public static Dictionary<int, Transformable> classrooms = null;
 public static Dictionary<int, Transformable> institutions = null;
```

All classes in my project are implementing `Transformable`, in that interface is method `GetId()`. So after I load all objects I somehow need to display in `DataGrid` name of institution for a given classroom. One of the fields of `Classroom` is `Institution`, which is an `int`. That is a key for appropriate `Institution`.

```
<DataGrid Margin="1,0"  Name="dgClassrooms" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Classroom number" Binding="{Binding ClassroomNumber}" Width="*"/>
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"  Width="*"/>
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}"  Width="*"/>
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Computers" Binding="{Binding Computers}"  Width="*"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

```
public partial class RemoveInstitution : Window
{
      private Institution selectedInstitution;
      public RemoveInstitution(Institution selectedInstitution)
      {
           InitializeComponent();
           this.selectedInstitution = selectedInstitution;
           this.DataContext = this.selectedInstitution;
           dgClassrooms.ItemsSource = DataMapper.ClassroomsToList().FindAll(x => x.Active);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

I add this to my Window xaml file

```
<Window.Resources>
        <local:TestConverter x:Key="testConverter"></local:TestConverter>

</Window.Resources>
```

Before that I created TestConverter (I'll rename it latter), like this:

```
public class TestConverter : IValueConverter
{

            object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {


                Institution inst = (Institution)DataMapper.institutions[(int)value];

                return inst.Name;
            }

            object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
}
```

And back again in same xaml file, I add this one to appropriate DataGrid element:

```
<DataGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Classroom number" Binding="{Binding ClassroomNumber}" Width="*"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Header="Active" Binding="{Binding Active}"  Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Size" Binding="{Binding Size}"  Width="*"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Computers" Binding="{Binding Computers}"  Width="*"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Institution" Binding="{Binding Path = Institution, Converter={StaticResource testConverter} }"  Width="*"/>

</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Hope this is going to help someone!